# Pasting data into next empty column using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really new to VBA so this is some code that I found online and combined.
Right now there are 3 parts (the last part isn't that important to my question). The first part "compile" loops through all the files in a folder and calls the second part "copydata" which copies data under columns with the header "direction" or "instruction" and pastes it into a new sheet "Summary". Right now it pastes the new data into the first column but the new data gets overwritten every time a new file is opened. How can I update my code so that every time a file is opened, the new data is put into the next empty column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not tested*

```
Sub CopyData(OldWB As Worksheet, NewWB As Worksheet)
    Dim title As Range
    Dim lColumn As Long

    With OldWB.Rows(1)
        Set title = .Find("direction")
        If title Is Nothing Then Set title = .Find("instruction")
    End With

    'Get last used column, and add 1 (for next one)
    lColumn = NewWB.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    If Not title Is Nothing Then
        title.EntireColumn.Copy
        NewWB.Cells(1, lColumn).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
        NewWB.Columns(lColumn).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        NewWB.Columns.AutoFit
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```